# Favicon issue in website

Tags: behavior, favicon

I am using a favicon which is linked in all pages using `<link>` tag. This favicon is stored in a folder inside the root folder, and I have another favicon stored in the root folder also. When the site loads fully the favicon which I am referring to is shown correctly. But when I stop the site before loading completely then it shows the favicon from the root folder.

Is this the default/desired behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd say yes.

The only way the browser can find your correct favicon is by using the `<link>` tag. If that tag's not present or parsed correctly the browser will have to fall back on its default behaviour which is to look for a file called `favicon.ico` in the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about desired behaviour, but it is to be expected.  The browser will request /favicon.ico by default, and the `<link>` is considered an override.

You will find for most browsers, they will actually fetch both, but display the `<link>` by preference.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers, if they don't find a `<link rel="icon">` or `<link rel="shortcut icon">`, fall back on the old bog-standard of showing /favicon.ico . Some can be configured to avoid this (e.g. Opera has this in GUI config), some will look for /favicon.ico regardless.

This is an artifact of the Browser Dark Ages and no fault of your own.